# how to resolve python error "not all arguments converted while string formatting"

Tags: python, arguments, string-formatting

When i execute below program

```
import MySQLdb
cn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="mysqlroot", 
db="sv_data")
cursor = cn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = '10011'")
for (addressline1, zipcode) in cursor:
print(addressline1, zipcode)
cursor.close()
cn.close()
```

it works fine. However when i try to add a parameter in query, like below

```
import MySQLdb
 cn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="****",     
db="sv_data")
cursor = cn.cursor()

a="10011"
cursor.execute("select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = 
%s", (a))
for (addressline1, zipcode) in cursor:
 print(addressline1, zipcode)

cursor.close()
cn.close()
```

getting error ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

can you please advise how to fix this. I tried various options. zipcode is varchar field in mysqldb

Comment: did you try - `select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = '%s'` as query ?

Comment: what is the traceback you are getting?

Comment: in <module>
    cursor.execute("select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = '%s'", (a))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)

ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the argument. you are rather giving it a string.

Try this.

```
cursor.execute("select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = %s" % a )
```

The best way to do is to separate your arguments and `sql_query`

```
_sql = "select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = {0}"
cursor.execute(_sql.format(a))
```

Comment: The docs show that this is valid: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Thanks. This works. However having a % is security issue. can you please help with passing as argument also

Comment: This shouldn't be an accepted answer. This is horribly unsafe.

Comment: @Adisheshaiah what if you use a dict argument like shown in the docs? Does it say the same thing?

Comment: I am using the second part. by separating arguments and query, and that works fine

Comment: What if you add a comma to the parameter. i.e. `(a,)`. I'm betting it's actually trying to iterate through the string 10011.

Comment: @CoryMadden op ask for the variable that he used, there can be many cases for any datastructure.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay I was only asking to see if it raised the same error. It's called debugging.

Comment: Please read the first three comments. This is not the proper way to execute sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that `cursor` is reading `(a)` as just a string and sees multiple values in it that aren't being converted(`1, 0, 0, 1, 1`). So if you add a comma like so:

```
cursor.execute("select addressline1, zipcode from sv_address where zipcode = %s", (a,))
```

I believe that will work properly.

For instance, look at this function and the outcome:

```
In [28]: def t(arg):
    ...:     print(type(arg))
    ...:     

In [29]: t(('a'))
<class 'str'>
```

The argument isn't being read as a tuple, it's being read as a string.